# Set audio/video files of single recorded video file using ngCamRecorder and run simultaneously

Tags: angularjs, html, video, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am using ngCamRecorder for creating video file and its upload in two separate file (audio and video) after uploading I am struggling to display in browser

My Code when I video streaming using ngCamRecorder

```
<?php

$tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$name2 = uniqid().'.webm';

/* s3 server code */
/*
include('s3/uploads3.php');
$s3obj = new amazons3video();
$result = $s3obj->uploadFileS3($tmp_name, $name2);
*/


$target_path = "/public_html/myproject/videos/";
$target_file = $target_path.$name;
$complete =$target_path.$name2;
$_SESSION['videoFileName'] = $name2;
$com = fopen($complete, "ab");
error_log($target_path);
    $in = fopen($tmp_name, "rb");

    if ( $in ) {
        while ( $buff = fread( $in, 1048576 ) ) {
            fwrite($com, $buff);
        }   
    }
    fclose($in);
fclose($com);

?>
```